# Cordova media plugin ios "Failed to start recording using AVAudioRecorder code:1"

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-media-plugin

This question is asked before but its accepted answer does not work.
The problem is that I cannot record audio on ios using cordova/ionic 2  application, I have tried the ionic native which fails without error, now trying the cordova-media-plugin which gives the error:`"Failed to start recording using AVAudioRecorder code:1".`
here is my code

```
      this.file.createFile(this.dir, this.filename, true).then(f => {
        this.m = new (<any>window).Media(this.dir + this.filename,function(e){alert('Success');},
    function(e){alert('failed'+JSON.stringify(e));});
this.m.startRecord();
   }).catch(e=>alert(JSON.stringify(e)));
```

`this.dir` has the value of tempDirectory and filename is .wav same result with mp3

Please help, Thanks

Comment: You'r apps have permisson to access microphone ?

Comment: I think it has, I set using camera permission plugin, before it used to crash for lacking this permission, do you suggest something to make sure it is not permission issue, I would try anything @EnzoBLANCHON

Comment: I use this plugin for check permission : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin
I don't give you exemple, the documentation of this plugin is awesome!

Comment: I add this to a real answer if someone else need help, it's clearer I thinks

Answer (score 0):

It's can be a permisson problem cause on a old version of this plugin (cordova 3.0) the code 1 was :

> Missing Android permission

To be sure you have the permission to record you can used [this plugin](http://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)

An example :

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isMicrophoneAuthorized(function(authorized){
    if (authorized) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Its not permission issues, just checked the permissions using diagnostic plugin